# DNS infrastructure conception Issues

Tags: dns, bind, powerdns

I am writing to you because I have a conception problem for my DNS infrastructure.DNS. My infrastructure is composed of a DNS machine (recursive or forwarding) and another authoritatve that has say views according to the source of the client (we can assimilate it to Bind even if it is not the case). This Auhoritative machine should not be queried directly but must go through the other. To summarize here is the infrastructure:

```
> Client Location 1     Client Location 2   Client Location 3
>               \           |           /
>               DNS Recursive ou Forwarding
>                           |           
>               DNS Authoratitve with 3 « views ».
```

I thought of different solutions to solve these problems :

- Create different ports on the DNS Recursive (or Forwading), each port containing a DNS that would correspond to a view that would query the Authoritative DNS (and thus recognize the origin). But I find this solution rather ugly and that will quickly increase if the number of views increases.
- Use the DNS extension : EDNS to forward the client network (but that seems pretty complicated).

I wanted to know if you have other solutions and if not what would be the best.
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The first solution does not seem really workable as there is nearly no way to change from the default DNS port in various end clients OS. You would instead need separate recursive nameservers on separate IP addresses and each client configured with the specific nameserver it needs to use.

The second solution can work, it is ECS the "EDNS Client Subnet" feature, described in [RFC7871](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7871.txt) and supported in various nameservers. See for example in Bind: https://www.isc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/ecs.pages.pdf

Now are you really sure you need this setup or that this is the only way to achieve your goals? It is difficult to propose other ideas as you describe from the get go your solution but not really your problem initially nor your constraints.

For example, it may be solved in some cases by just configuring each client with a different domain search list. `client1` would have `client1.example.com` as suffix, `client2` would have `client2.example.com` and so on. Now, with only one standard recursive nameserver and one authoritative one for `example.com` without any kind of extension or complicated setup, when `client1` attempts to resolve `www` it will (may) get a different reply than `client2` also attempting to resolve `www` as the final two fully qualified domain name would be indeed different (`www.client1.example.com` vs `www.client2.example.com`), because of the different search lists. This of course depends a lot on what kind of applications are running on each client.

The use of simpler nameservers such as `dnsmasq` may also help, but again your space problem is not defined enough to be sure what to suggest.